# Bad Image Error by Google App engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

My problem when trying to resize an image using the image class in google app engine. 
The error is displayed below. This happens for every type of image including .jpg,.png,etc
Internal Server Error

The server has either erred or is incapable of performing the requested operation.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.5.2\webapp2.py", line 1535, in __call__
    rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.5.2\webapp2.py", line 1529, in __call__
    rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.5.2\webapp2.py", line 1278, in default_dispatcher
    return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.5.2\webapp2.py", line 1102, in __call__
    return handler.dispatch()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.5.2\webapp2.py", line 572, in dispatch
    return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.5.2\webapp2.py", line 570, in dispatch
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\prudhvir\Desktop\projectbyprudhviraj\main.py", line 252, in post
    avatar = images.resize(user_dp, 32, 32)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\images\__init__.py", line 1095, in resize
    return rpc.get_result()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 612, in get_result
    return self.__get_result_hook(self)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\images\__init__.py", line 886, in execute_transforms_hook
    raise _ToImagesError(e, self._blob_key)
BadImageError
```

Comment: do you have pil installed?